# What are the properties of the Topology which generates the Lebesgue sigma algebra?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/89344/71829) shows that the Lebesgue sigma algebra, i.e. the sigma algebra of Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, is actually the Borel algebra of a topology $T$ on $\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows: $U\in T$ if $U=O-N$, where $O$ is open in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $N$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

My question is, what are the properties of this topology $T$?  Which of the [separation axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom) does it satisfy?  Which of the [countability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countability) does it satisfy?  And is it metrizable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations: this topology is ccc (in $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T})$, every family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets is at most countable), e.g. because of the $\sigma$-finiteness of the Lebesgue measure. But it's not separable (so also not second countable), as every countable set is closed (being measure $0$, or a null set). So it's certainly not metrisable (see e.g. my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430113/is-a-separable-and-metrizable-space-second-countable/2812134#2812134) which implies that ccc implies separable for second metrisable spaces). It is not Lindelöf as the Cantor set is uncountable closed and discrete as a subspace.

It's Hausdorff, being finer than the Euclidean topology, but not normal or regular because you cannot separate $\sqrt{2}$ from the closed set $\mathbb{Q}$.

It's not first countable, by a diagonalisation argument: if $U_n, n \in \omega$ would be a local base at $x$, for each $n$ pick $p_n \in U_n\setminus \{x\}$ and note that no $U_n$ is contained in the open neighbourhood $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{p_n: n \in \omega\}$ of $x$. In fact any convergent sequence in this space is eventually constant, just like we can show for the coarser co-countable topology.

So it's a pretty badly behaved topology in all. I seem to recall it has some standard name, but I cannot recall it right now. I found [one paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/SPS_1971__5__290_0.pdf) online that considers it and calls it the "essential topology" on $\mathbb{R}$.